# infinite loop on a redirect route

Tags: php, symfony

i have a problem i dont know how to stop it. i have an infinite loop on a redirect route, i tried to redirect a user if he has not accept some condition
this is my code :

```
 /**
     * AcceptanceListener constructor.
     * @param $router
     * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
     * @param UserManager $userManager
     * @param AuthorizationChecker $checker
     */
    public function __construct(
        $router,
        TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage,
        UserManager $userManager,
        AuthorizationChecker $checker
    ) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->role = $checker;
    }

    /**
     * To checked all the routes
     *
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        if ($this->role->isGranted('ROLE_USER')
            && !$this->userManager->hasAccepted($user)
        ) {
            $this->redirect = $this->router->generate('accept_');
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->redirect));
        }
    }
```

someone can help me please?

Comment: don't do GDPR on the PHP side. Symfony caches files, you're going to run into trouble.

Comment: Can you please show a copy of your whole security.yaml? Must be something with your firewall config.

Comment: Also, where is the accept route located

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the route is not the same, then redirect

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $route_name = $event->getRequest()->get('_route');

            if ($route_name != 'accept_') {

        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        if ($this->role->isGranted('ROLE_USER')
            && !$this->userManager->hasAccepted($user)
        ) {
            $this->redirect = $this->router->generate('accept_');
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->redirect));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ohhh thank you very much, i did a 'if' too but its was the wrong way